# Using neo4j load csv with headers: how can I use the map in a merge?

Tags: csv, neo4j

While loading from a file, if I do:

```
 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/Users/csv.dat' AS row RETURN row;
```

I get back a map for each row, e.g.:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| row                                                                  |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| {id -> "1", prop1 -> "foo1", prop2 -> "foo2"} |
| {id -> "2", prop1 -> "goo1", prop2 -> "goo2"} |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now is there a way I can use those maps in a MERGE, so I don't have to spell out every property, i.e.:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/Users/csv.dat' AS row
MERGE (n:node {row} ) 
RETURN n;
```

Obviously neo4j doesn't like that syntax, but that's what I'm trying to do; then I can make a generic query to construct different types of nodes.

Thanks,
M Hodges

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to be explicit about your node properties, like this:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:/Users/csv.dat' AS row
MERGE (n:node {prop1: row.prop1, prop2: row.prop2} ) 
RETURN n;
```

You can also use array indexing, i.e. refer to `row[1]` instead of `row.prop1` so that you can talk about columns in the CSV file.

But I don't think that you can make a generic query in the sense that in order to `LOAD` some CSV, you have to know certain things about the format ahead of time.  I'm not sure it's possible to create any arbitrary set of nodes from any file by using CSV "metadata".

Comment: is there a way to use an array range index? as in row[1..6]?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  In this case it would be easier to cut the CSV down with a text editor first.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Frobber, I think you're right on that.  So what I did was write a utility to run the queries.  My application has many types of entities loaded from different files.  The task runner opens each of the csv files, reads the header line, and constructs a property string, which it then plugs into the query, something like this:

```
var query =  "LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:{filename}' AS line ";
    query += "MERGE (n:node {properties}) RETURN n";
var sep='', keys = headerline.split(',');
var props = '{';
   for( var i=0; i<keys.length; i++){  props += sep + keys[i] + ':line.' + keys[i];   sep = ','; }  
props += '}';
query = query.replace(/\{properties\}/, props);
query = query.replace(/\{filename\}/, '/Users/me/csv.dat');
```

Clumsy to be rebuilding maps like this, but c'est la vie.